# What is an efficient way to read a line of integers from the STDIN in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have tried

```
STDIN.gets.chomp.split(" ")
```

And then converted each elements in the array to Integer.

But I believe there should be a better solution.

Comment: What is your criteria for "better"? Shorter?

Comment: Seriously? How much faster does it need to be?

Comment: Never mind. I had an interview just now and was asked to do a similar task. Anyway, your approach is really elegant, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the integers cannot be negative:

```
nums = gets.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i)
```

Or for arbitrary input:

```
nums = gets.strip.split(/\s+/).map(&:to_i)
```

The key here is using using [`Array#map`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-map) to invoke a block for each value in the array, creating a new array of the results for each. Then we use [`Symbol#to_proc`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Symbol.html#method-i-to_proc) (invoked by the ampersand syntax of Ruby) to tersely invoke the `to_i` method on each string.

For example, `foo.map(&:to_i)` is equivalent to `foo.map{ |o| o.to_i }`.

**Edit**: it will be *slightly* faster to map the array in place, and split only on a single space if you know that is the only separator, and to not use Symbol#to_proc:

```
nums = gets.chomp.split(' ').map!{ |o| o.to_i }
```

However, you are unlikely to see more than a very minor improvement here. Are you certain that you need this faster? What is your data, and what are your profiling results showing that this is a critical place where you need more speed?

Comment: It turns out that import data is not a real critical issue in my problem. But your code is helpful to improve my code. Thank you. Still wondering why ruby dose not have a direct method to read integers.

Comment: Why should Ruby have a method to 'read integers'? What about dates, floats, booleans, URLs, directories, file paths? Why is one delimiter (spaces) better than another (commas,hyphens,newlines)? As a good programming language, Ruby provides you with general purpose methods, and its up to you to string them together in a reasonable fashion. Programming is mostly about "path finding": knowing what data do you have, what data do you have, and all transformation steps can you take, what's the simplest way to get from A to B.